# Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь сделать отправку емейла на фреймворке Spring.

Вот мой код:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmail", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void sendEmail() {



        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo("turbo_char@mail.ru");
        message.setSubject("DishOline");
        message.setText("Hello user");

        emailSender.send(message);

    }
```

Конфигурация почтового сервера в application.properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.mail.ru
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=dishonline@mail.ru
spring.mail.password=??????
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust = smtp.mail.ru
```

Но при отправке емейла я получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой

Answer (score 0):

Надо поменять порт на 465

25 - стандартный порт для соединения по SMTP без шифрования.
Таким образом SMTP-авторизация на mail.Ru не передается